# Splitting and classifying txt lines into a table

Tags: r, text, data-wrangling

I have a long word document that lists items like this:

1. Item 1

   - entry1
   - entry2
   - entry3
2. Item 2

   - entry1
   - entry2
   - entry3
3. (etc...)

The items are species names, and the entries are corresponding location and date information, but that doesn't matter much now.

I am trying to get this extremely long document into a reasonable table/tibble object in R, for which my idea was to use:

```
library (stringr)
data <- readLines("data.txt")
test_data <- str_sub(data, 1, 3)
```

and then assign another vector with the "Item" identity of each element of "data" (i.e. what species each date+location corresponds with). I was trying to use a for loop for this and test whether each line starts with "   " or not, but I am stuck.

```
results <- vector (length = length(data))
   for (i in 1:length(data)) {
   if (test_data[i] != "   ") {
      results[i] = data[i]
   } else {
        while #here I am stuck
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi :) do you always have 3 entries per item?

Comment: Hi! No, the number of entries varies a lot.

Comment: Does the format is always like, for Items, (integer).Item and for entry, (space or tab)entries?

Comment: Yes, each item directly starts with letters (a binomial species name e.g. Homo sapiens). Then each entry starts with twelve blank spaces "            ", followed by words (Location names and then date info in the same line).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach based on the fact that "each entry starts with twelve spaces".

```
# fake data
obj <- c("Item 1",
"            entry1",
"            entry2",
"            entry3",
"            entry4",
"Item 2",
"            entry1",
"            entry2",
"            entry3"
)

writeLines(obj, con = "data2.txt")


# read in and convert
library(tidyverse)

dat <- readLines("data.txt", skipNul = TRUE)

dat |>
  enframe() |>
  separate(
    value,
    into = c("item", "entry"),
    sep = "\\s{12}",
    convert = TRUE,
    fill = "right"
  ) |>
  mutate(item = na_if(item, "")) |>
  fill(item, .direction = "down") |>
  filter(!(is.na(entry)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got something to start with. The idea is to load your text file as a single long string and then break it into pieces corresponding to Item + entries and store it in a list. Lastly, use `lapply` on the list to separate Item and entries.

```
filename <- "test.txt"
# read your file a single long string
step1 <- readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size)
# find the pattern that separate each Item (from a copy/paste of the example it is "\r\n\r\n") and make a list of items
# with associated entries
step2 <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(step1, split = "\r\n\r\n")))
# lastly split the vectors from step2
step3 <- lapply(step2, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\r\n    ")))
```

Output:

```
> step3
[[1]]
[1] "Item 1" "entry1" "entry2" "entry3"

[[2]]
[1] "Item 2" "entry1" "entry2" "entry3"
```

From here you can start using "usual" tools to clean your data and organize it *e.g.*

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, step3))
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 2:ncol(df))
df <- df[, -2]
names(df) <- c("Items", "Entries")
df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Items  Entries
  <chr>  <chr>  
1 Item 1 entry1 
2 Item 1 entry2 
3 Item 1 entry3 
4 Item 2 entry1 
5 Item 2 entry2 
6 Item 2 entry3
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful